# How to regex a word that does not contain spaces?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to regex that a value has no spaces (`^[\S]*$`) and only contains letters (`\w+`). But how do I combine these two to one regex?

Expected result should be:

```
oneword: true
one word: false
1word: false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you may want something like (if the empty string is to be valid):

```
^[A-Za-z]*$
```

`\w` contains digits and `_` too, so that would match `1word`.

Comment: + for non-empty strings :)

Answer (score 4):

For matching letters only this regex would be enough:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

- `\w` means letter, digits and underscore

Answer (score 1):

`\w` not only match alphabets, but also match digits, underscore(`_`). To match only alphabets, use:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-regex solution, perhaps you could try something like this:

```
public boolean valid(final String string){
    for(final char c : string.toCharArray())
        if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\p{Alpha}` which is an alphabetic character:`[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]`

With the above your regular expression will be `\p{Alpha}+`, which matches one or more of alphabetic characters. This ignores digits, underscores, whitespaces etc.

For more info look at section **POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)** in [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).